# Using glm syntax to fit complex models?

Tags: r, formula, glm

Is it possible to fit the following regression model with glm()?

[image]
that can be written like this:

[image]

That's, 8 input variables but only 2 parameters, a and b.

Maybe with some kind of transformation?
Or should I use some other method/package instead, such as GAM?, How?

Another simple model, with one parameter
[image]
How do you write it with glm formula syntax?

OK, I've found that my example could be easily written as
[image]

Then I need to define two new variables and use a simple linear regression.